# Angularjs bad request URL

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a problem with the wrong URL in Request URL. I have api in Laravel, the address to him is: api.shop.local - this is vhost. When I send a request from angular using POST, in the Network tab in the console, in RequestURL there appears: client.shop.local instead of api.shop.local.

What I doing wrong?

This is my code: 
JS

```
$scope.login = function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'authenticate',
            data: {email: data.username, password: data.password}
        }).then(
                function (res) {
                    console.log('succes !', res.data);
                },
                function (err) {
                    console.log('error...', err);
                }
        );
    };
```

And routes in api Laravel:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function()
{
    Route::resource('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController', ['only' => ['index']]);
    Route::post('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController@authenticate');
});
```

Comment: Did you set your base url to api.shop.local anywhere in the angularjs?

Comment: Yes, but in RequestURL always is : http://client.shop.local/api.shop.local

Comment: Show the code where you set the base url, chances are you have a problem there. The code you posted doesn't mention `api.shop.local` anywhere

Comment: I set it up earlier. I did it that way : $scope.url = $location.host(); but console.log give me client.shop.local instead api.shop.local